# Задать константы (или статические переменные) класса

Tags: php

Есть класс, в котором есть набор статических функций, которые используют константы этого класса.

Так получилось, что константы теперь необходимо формировать конкатенацией двух строк (объявленная в define и простой строкой в виде кавычек).

Чтобы решить данную проблему, я перевел константы в статические переменные, и теперь думаю где производить вычисление этих переменных, т.к. синтаксис мне не позволяет объединять их сразу.

Самое лучшее, что пришло в голову, это вызвать статический метод из вне 1 раз:

```
define('XX_VAR', 'value');

class x {
    public static $z;

    public static function Init()
    {
        self::$z = XX_VAR.'zd';
    }

}    
x::Init(); // т.е. по сути это вызовется 1 раз за сценарий

echo x::$z;
```

**Как можно это дело красивее организовать?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему константа? Что насчёт простой инкапсуляции?

```
public class MyClass {
    private static $conts = "1235";
    public static function getConsts() {
        return self::$conts;
    }
}
```

Получить переменную можно, изменить нельзя. Ну, вне класса.

Comment: проблема собственно не том что могу изменить значение, а в том что не могу заранее задать вот так:

     private static $conts = "1235"."sdfsd";

А для функций, слишком много таких параметров, получается громоздко

p.s. зловещий рейтинг 666 )))

Comment: Подарил единичку, самого пугает)

Comment: @dimka3210 666 - число интереснее )

Answer (score 1):

я думаю лучше переменную z сделать скрытой, и возвращать ее через функцию, чтобы не было возможности изменить ее извне класса http://pastebin.com/4KJkkPQ3

Comment: такой же вариант как у Димка :)

Comment: почти одновременно отписались)